# Weird Pending sectors

Tags: hard-drive, bad-sectors

I have a WD Elements 1TB external HDD that has been getting some pending sectors in the last few months but in a seemingly weird fashion. I have looked on other threads but so far haven't seen anything similar.

I use both Windows and Linux and on windows use HDTune to read the smart data. Once in a while, it warns of Pending Sector Count: 1.

Well I found a thread that indicates that it may be possible to fix/test the sector using hdparm in linux. I use smartctl tests to find the sectors LBA and then use the command: hdparm --read-sector "sector LBA" "device" to test the sector which yields "SG_IO: Bad/Missing sense data" along with some hexadecimal stuff. What I've noticed though is that the pending sector always happens in groups. Say the first pending sector LBA is 1792406056, then sectors 1792406056-1792406063 all yield the same result in hdparm. It's always in groups of 8 or more.

I then use the command: "hdparm --write-sector 1792406056 /dev/sdb --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing" to force write the sector, which i then have to repeat for the next 7 sectors as well (once it was the next 15 sectors). When i then did a smartctl test and checked the results, the Pending Sector Count had gone back to 0, yet the reallocated sector count was also still 0, along with reallocated event count, which makes me believe that it didn't remap it because it successfully wrote to it and read it.

Anyone know why this is happening? I checked other threads and the others always talk about a single sector or several in different places. Mine always occurs in groups of 8 or sometimes 16, and then when i use the hdparm, no reallocations occur, but the pending sector count goes down and i can read the sectors afterwards with hdparm, no problem. Anyone know what is going on?

Anyway, I'm planning to buy another HDD soon and i have 2 others spare already so i have a backup if this drive fails.

Here's a recent one i copied from the terminal:

```
**root@kali**:~# smartctl --all /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-4.0.0-kali1-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Elements / My Passport (USB, AF)
Device Model:     WDC WD10JMVW-11S5XS1
Serial Number:    WD-WX31AC2U3838
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 6adc0ab38
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Oct 30 19:26:17 2015 PHT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status not supported: Incomplete response, ATA output registers missing
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Warning: This result is based on an Attribute check.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 121) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (16980) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 185) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x70b5) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   189   185   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       22546
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   181   179   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       1933
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       670
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2048
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       389
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       178
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   185   185   000    Old_age   Always       -       47239
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   108   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       39
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      2047         1792406056
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1969         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      1969         1792240312
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1699         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      1698         1792238904
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1568         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      1568         1753687219
# 8  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      1568         1753687218
# 9  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      1568         1753687218
#10  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      1568         1753687217
#11  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      1567         1753687216

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.


**root@kali**:~# hdparm --read-sector 1792406056 /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
reading sector 1792406056: SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 03 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
succeeded
2e2e 642f 7665 6369 7365 702f 6963 3030
3030 303a 2f30 3030 3030 303a 3a30 6131
302e 752f 6273 2f31 2d31 2f31 2d31 2e31
2f32 2d31 2e31 3a32 2e31 2f30 6f68 7473
2f37 6174 6772 7465 3a37 3a30 2f30 3a37
3a30 3a30 2f30 6c62 636f 2f6b 6473 0062
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

**root@kali**:~# hdparm --write-sector 1792406056 --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
re-writing sector 1792406056: succeeded

**root@kali**:~# hdparm --read-sector 1792406056 /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
reading sector 1792406056: succeeded
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

**The above hdparm was repeated 7 more time till sector 1792406063. The last is the end result. No pending sectors anymore, but no reallocations either.**

**root@kali**:~# smartctl --all /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-4.0.0-kali1-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Elements / My Passport (USB, AF)
Device Model:     WDC WD10JMVW-11S5XS1
Serial Number:    WD-WX31AC2U3838
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 6adc0ab38
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Oct 30 19:36:26 2015 PHT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status not supported: Incomplete response, ATA output registers missing
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Warning: This result is based on an Attribute check.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (16980) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 185) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x70b5) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   189   185   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       22550
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   181   179   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       1933
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       670
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2048
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       389
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       178
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   185   185   000    Old_age   Always       -       47244
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   108   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       39
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2048         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      2047         1792406056
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1969         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      1969         1792240312
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1699         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      1698         1792238904
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1568         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      1568         1753687219
# 9  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      1568         1753687218
#10  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      1568         1753687218
#11  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      1568         1753687217
#12  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      1567         1753687216

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Sorry about the Bold SMART Text. It has a Hashtag before it and it made it bold.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/583480/why-does-my-usb-hdd-returns-sg-io-bad-missing-sense-data seems to make sense. Is this drive 3.5 inch or 2.5 inch?

Comment: It is a 2.5 inch external hdd

Comment: ahh bother. I think the issue MIGHT be with the usb/sata interface bit of it, but those drives have that built into the drive controller, so you can't hook the drive into a pc to test

Comment: Ok. What about the pending sector count thing? Is it normal for that to go down but the Reallocated Sector count to remain at 0? Also...I'm not sure if it's relevant to this specific thing, but I have noticed some strange things about my USB ports but I'm not sure if it can cause this. Should I detail it?

Comment: That *is* odd. The random read failures are odd too.

Comment: The read failures are at different times. In total, there has been 4 counts of pending sectors in the past month or two. Each time, I've done the above method with hdparm, and each time, the sector was fixed at the end without any reallocation occuring. I believe the first time had around 16 sectors, all one after the other, show the SG_IO error, and the next three times were all around 8 consecutive. Also, all those LBA's are part of my Windows C:\ partition.

Comment: ", but I have noticed some strange things about my USB ports but I'm not sure if it can cause this. Should I detail it?" yes. Also why do you have windows on an *external* drive?

Comment: Well, @TacticX, I'm sorry to hear about your concerns with the WD Elements. However, the current pending sector count doesn't necessarily mean that the 1 unstable sector will go bad. The raw value indicates the total number of sectors waiting for remapping. It's also possible that the sector will be read successfully later, and then the value will decrease. According to the SMART data there are no remapped a.k.a. bad sectors, so I don't think there's anything to worry about just yet. However, it's highly recommended to have backups of your data. Better safe than sorry, right? Hope I helped! :)

Comment: @Journeyman Geek: I detailed it on another thread because it affected quite a few things, but in short, I have 2 USB ports on the right of my laptop. One of them has the WD HDD plugged in, and the other is a sound card. For some reason, my sound card can pick up the sound of the HDD heads moving through the USB port (I tested to make sure it isn't random noise). Also, anything that's connected to the port is extremely sensitive. One touch and it disconnects temporarily. Here's the thread: http://superuser.com/questions/993809/could-this-be-a-faulty-laptop-adapter-or-something-else

Comment: Thanks for the details SuperSoph_WD. It rests my mind a bit, though it is unnerving opening my laptop screen and seeing a nice yellow banner on HDTune. Also @Journeyman Geek, my laptop internal HDD died and since i can't buy another yet, I (painstakingly) installed windows on the external drive. I also have Kali on another eHDD which is how i have access to smartctl and all that.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1218312/pending-sector-issue-does-this-mean-the-hdd-is-failing/1218317#1218317